# Get correct position on header with show/hide function JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

im on the way to get scroll hide/show function work on header section, i made some codepen to show you how works on my page, but if you check it, when you scroll down header didn't get top of the page, when you scroll up it show correctly, is anyone able to guide me :)

```js
var prev = 0;
var nav = document.getElementById("js-scroll-top");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || 0;

  if (scrollTop > prev) {
    nav.classList.add("hidden");
  } else {
    nav.classList.remove("hidden");
  }

  prev = scrollTop;
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  background: #FFFF00;
  height: 8000px;
}

.nav {
  background: #111;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

.nav.hidden {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #fff;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 3.75rem;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
```

```html
<div id="js-scroll-top" class="nav">Scroll to show/hide this bar!</div>
<div class="header">header</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `.nav.hidden` instead of translating the element, use an `absolute` [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

So as soon as the element above the header gets an absolute position, the header will slide up to take its place.

Actually, this may lead the header to go up immediately without following the animation time.
Better if you swap the translation for an `height` that goes to `0`.

I'm not providing snippets cause am writing from my phone.

Comment: thanks for your tips, i have searched and this is a best solution, make that transition for an height that goes to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `top` of the `.header` element as that defines the distance from the top that it "*sticks*" to.

I would move the nav controlling class to the `html` element, and use it to also modify the top of the header.

Something like

```js
var prev = 0;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || 0;

  if (scrollTop > prev) {
    document.documentElement.classList.add("hidden-nav");
  } else {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove("hidden-nav");
  }

  prev = scrollTop;
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  background: #FFFF00;
  height: 8000px;
}

.nav {
  background: #111;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

.hidden-nav .nav {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #fff;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 3.75rem;
  transition: top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}
.hidden-nav .header{
  top:0rem;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
```

```html
<div id="js-scroll-top" class="nav">Scroll to show/hide this bar!</div>
<div class="header">header</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and advice, I have used one of those tips like using a top container that controls both (navigation and header). But I think better solution is to use "height" as a transition to 0.